# How to embed an iframe with custom styled xml content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xml, iframe

I am making a website and the client requires some news from BBC. I have looked on the internet on how to do this for 3 hours with no success. I would like to use an iframe to insert a XML BCC file and style it.

What I have tried so far:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/rss/rss_radio1.xml"></iframe>
```

and when i try editing it in anyway it doesnt seem to work. I understand that the file is not local so it is really difficult to edit but is there any way around this?

URL of XML file: http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/rss/rss_radio1.xml

Any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a parser for the XML and handle the display of the data yourself. For example you could parse the XML and add the data into /react/vuejs/angular components or just use a vanilla approach. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xml/xml_parsers.htm

TLDR: can not be done through pure css